# trying to enable cookies but getting a cookies not enabled response

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, request, http-post

In my node.js server, I'm trying to log in to a page and I'm using request like this:

```
var request = require('request');
request = request.defaults({jar: true});
```

And then I have this:

```
request.post({url: loginUrl, formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

In the response I can see that it is posting the authentication details correctly, but it says I can't log in because I have to enable cookies. 'jar' is set to 'true' and I npm installed 'tough-cookie' as per the request docs but that didn't take care of it. Any ideas are very appreciated!

Comment: Think about the sequence of events when you log in to this site using a browser. When you navigate to the site, you GET a URL, at this point the server is probably sending a cookie. Then when you log in, you POST the authentication data along with the cookie you got in the initial request - this is how the server knows if you have cookies enabled or not. What you are doing is skipping the GET, and therefore have no cookie to send in the POST, which is why you get the cookies not enabled problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make post with cookies first of all You've to get cookies to store it and then make a request.
Try to do request to the page where is these form and then post to loginUrl.
Try this:

```
var request = require('request');
request = request.defaults({jar: true});

var urlWithLoginForm = 'http://some.domain.com/auth';
var loginUrl = urlWithLoginForm+'/attempt';
var formData = {'username': 'user1', 'password': 'blablabla'};

request(urlWithLoginForm, function() { // initialising cookies by doing http get
  // so now we have cookies in jar, now we can make post request
  request.post({url: loginUrl, formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('upload failed:', err);
    }
    console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you enabled cookies in the browser your using to access the website. That is normally what is meant by "You need to enable cookies"

Comment: Ah I see. The way I read the question was he had a webpage setup in node.js that he was trying to log into. Looking a little closer I see now he is trying to access another site from node.js